# Search string with special characters in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to search a string in mongo which is stored with special characters

```
db.getCollection('tb_tickets').find({"workflow_fields.label": "3~!@#$%^&*()__+}{|":<>?/.,';\][NAME"})
```

My use case doesn't allow me to first escape the special characters and then store in mongo.
How can I search `3~!@#$%^&*()__+}{|":<>?/.,';\][NAME` in mongo query.

Comment: can you provide example documents? Because it is not clear what you actually storing in MongoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the quotation mark: `"3~!@#$%^&*()__+}{|\":<>?/.,';\][NAME"` (note the `\` before the `"`)

```
> db.test_coll.insert({string: `3~!@#$%^&*()__+}{|":<>?/.,';\][NAME`});
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.test_coll.find({string: "3~!@#$%^&*()__+}{|\":<>?/.,';\][NAME" });
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cdafcb1176f787fae2db871"), "string" : "3~!@#$%^&*()__+}{|\":<>?/.,';][NAME" }
```

(If you take a look at your question, you can tell that something is going awry because the syntax highlighting isn't correctly highlighting your string.)